# while publishing artifacts from jenkins to scp repository getting error

Tags: jenkins, jsch

previously we used seperate server to publish artifacts at that time every thing working fie.
Recently we changed new dev server while publishing artifact to that server from jenkins after successful build i am getting below error. i've given all the permissions my directory(777).

```
scp connecting to 10.10.32.33
scp uploading file: '/apps/com/jenkinsdir/services/services.war'
Error: failed to upload files
3. permission denied
at com.jcraft.jsch.channelsftp.throwstatusError(channelSftpjava.2289)
at com.jcraft.jsch.channelsftp._Put(chanelSftp.java.485)
at com.jcraft.jsch.channelsftp.Put(chanelSftp.java.439)
at com.jcraft.jsch.channelsftp.Put(chanelSftp.java.406)
at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPsite.upload(SCPsite.java.239)
```

can anyone give suggestion how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using public key authentication? Did you accidentally give permissions `0777`  for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (or whatever your private key file is) at the ssh server computer? I think that will give permission denied to remote user trying to connect using that key. The permissions for that should be `0600`.

It shouldn't hurt if you do `chmod -R go-rxw ~/.ssh`, either (well, unless you have some server process running as another user, accessing your public key file).